# SQLException Occured

Tags: asp.net

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I was trying database connection. But I am getting this error. Please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace OLSWebApp
{
    public partial class ItemTypeWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static string constr = "server=DESKTOP-3N4UH9N; user=sa; pwd=ZEESHAN@123; Initial Catalog=Online Order System";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);

            conn.Open();

            string q = "Insert INTO ItemType values ('"+ TypeIdTextBox.Text +"'), ('"+ TypeTextBox.Text +"'),('"+ NameTextBox.Text +"')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

con.Open() statement generates error..

Comment: Please include full error message into question (as text)

Comment: I think your SQL server instance name may be wrong or please check the SQL Serve Mixed Authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server Connection types please first read this document.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

For your example I think `DESKTOP-3N4UH9N` is your local PC not the server instance name, isn't it?

Please first find the server instance name by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Please try below codes

**Standard Security**

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
"Server=myServerAddress; " + 
"Database=myDataBase;" + 
"User Id=myUsername;" +
"Password=myPassword;"
conn.Open();
```

**Trusted Connection**

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
   "Server=myServerAddress;" +
   "Database=myDataBase;" +
   "Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn.Open();
```

**Connection to a SQL Server instance**

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
  "Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;" +
  "Database=myDataBase;" +
  "User Id=myUsername;" +
  "Password=myPassword;"
conn.Open();
```

**Integrated Security**

```
  using System.Data.SqlClient;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=MyLocalSqlServerInstance;" +
    "Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;" +
    "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
conn.Open();

string q = "Insert INTO ItemType values ('"+ TypeIdTextBox.Text +"'), ('"+ TypeTextBox.Text +"'),('"+ NameTextBox.Text +"')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

into this

```
conn.Open();
string q = "Insert INTO ItemType values (@id, @type ,@name)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TypeIdTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", TypeTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NameTextBox.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

make sure the connection can open without any error